# An animated processing icon, pure C

Tags: c, char, printf, sleep, usleep

I want to make an animated processing icon outputted in console via C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void render_processing_icon(int turnovers_qt) {
  char *icon_characters = "|/-\\\0";

  for (int i = 0; i < turnovers_qt * 8; i++) {
    printf("\b%c", icon_characters[i % 4]);

    usleep(500000); // sleep for a half of a second
  }

  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    render_processing_icon(2);

    printf("CONTROL MESSAGE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But after `usleep()` time (0.5s * turnovers * 8) is over, program outputs this (without any animation, as you've guess):

```
$ \
$ CONTROL MESSAGE
```

`sleep()` works the same, BASH `sleep` via `sytstem()` too. I just have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: "`char *icon_characters = "|/-\\\0";`" the `\0` is not needed and `icon_characters` should be a `char const*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are not flushing the `printf` to the terminal. To save time the terminal usually buffers output. At some point when the buffer is full or in some terminals when you write `\n` to the stream it will flush automatically.

Try using [`fflush(stdout)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before the `usleep` in your `for` loop to force this flush.